# how to connect spring batch with oracle database to save a file contents

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, spring-batch

I have created a file read write operation. how to save input file contents to the oracle database.then read this data from db and save to the other file.
**db.properties**

```
url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.41.30:1521:xe
user =rainfra_user_04
password =user2019
```

**multiple-writer.xml**

```
<!-- Parent Job -->
<job id="parentJob" job-repository="jobRepository" abstract="true">
    <!-- <listeners> <listener ref="jobListener" /> </listeners> -->
</job>

<job id="MultipleJob" parent="parentJob">
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="customReader"   processor="customProcessor" writer="Writer" commit-interval="10000" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
<!-- read a file -->
<beans:bean id="customReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <beans:property name="resource" value="file:sample.txt" />

    <beans:property name="lineMapper">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughLineMapper" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="strict" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="customProcessor" class="com.ibs.training.CustomProcessor"></beans:bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="db.properties" />
<!-- write a file -->
<beans:bean id="Writer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <beans:property name="resource" value="file:output.txt" />

    <beans:property name="lineAggregator">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: You sample reads from a file `sample.txt` and writes to another file `output.txt`. What's your question about the database? Do you want to write to both a file **and** a database table? If this is the case, you might need to look at the [CompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine i want to write sample.txt into database then read the data from database and write to another file

Comment: ok, I added an answer with some useful links. Hope it helps.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine in that link spring batch configuration is done through annotations.but here i did using xml.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/). It shows how to read data from a file and write it to a database.

For the other way around, aka reading data from a database table and writing it to a file, take a look at the [Trade example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#trade-job) from the official examples.